# TypeScript make `outFile` to include dependencies

Tags: typescript

It's possible to tell TypeScript compiler to bundle all files together into single build file using `outFile` option.

But it would bundle the *.ts files only and **none of the dependencies** from `node_modules` or the implementation of AMD loader.

I wonder if it's possible to tell TypeScript compiler to **bundle everything** in that file?

P.S.

I know about Brunch, WebPack and other bundle tools, but for simple cases it seems like an overkill, I'd like to get away with TS compiler only if possible.

Comment: `tsc` doesn't bundle modules sadly... but you CAN load modules straight into the browser without bundling, in the latest safari and chrome versions!(you'll need to load each separate module as a .js file using a script tag)

Comment: Thanks, also was thinking about that option as workaround, I guess it should be more or less ok.

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I've written SAMD for this use case: https://github.com/morris/samd

It provides a minimal AMD implementation, sufficient for TypeScript AMD bundles and dependencies included via regular script tags.

It does not bundle dependencies, but you can simply concatenate dependencies if you want a single-file bundle (see README).